# Changing app icon issue

Tags: android

I changed my android app icon and my problem is showed in two pictures

In the first picture showed the launcher i made 
https://ibb.co/mPNtVG
In the second picture showed the default icon.
https://ibb.co/ew4CPb
The second issue that i have is the notification icon showed on emulator but not on my phone (xiaomi redmi 3s)

The launcher icon created by android studio > configure image asset with icon type LancherIcons(Legacy only)

My android manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gui"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="activities.settings.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/settings_title"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">


        </activity>

        <service android:name="applications.AppIntentService" />
        <service android:name="recogniton_service.ForeGroundRecognition" />

    </application>
```

I can't find what goes wrong.

Comment: try to uninstall apk then reinstall on both devices

Comment: Opening the new PNG on the folder shows which icon?

Comment: add a complete package containing the ic_launcher with hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi resolution.